# List of tuples not indexing as expected

Tags: python, django

I have the following list of tuples:

```
[(2010, u'S03', u'AA26FedGovAccounts', 1.90537034315564, 46385659904.0), (2010, u'S03', u'AA27StLocGovAccounts', 1.5897291595379, 58351759360.0), (2010, u'S03', u'AA28CapitalAccounts', 1.79050465110027, 95550709760.0)]
```

When I use: `viewData[:][:]` it works as expected and outputs all the data.
When I use: `viewData[2][2]` it works correctly and outputs 'AA28CapitalAccounts'.
The problem is that both `viewData[2][:]` and `viewData[:][2]` are giving me the same result of: `(2010, u'S03', u'AA28CapitalAccounts', 1.79050465110027, 95550709760.0)`. I was expecting `viewData[:][2]` to give me a list of `u'AA26FedGovAccounts'`, `u'AA27StLocGovAccounts'`, and `u'AA28CapitalAccounts'`.

This is being run on a webserver using Django. The code is:

```
c = connections['default'].cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM {0}.\"{1}\"".format(analysis_schema, viewName))
viewData=c.fetchall()
values = { curDesc[2][0] : str(viewData[:][2]) }
```

Comment: What are you looking for -- e.g. how did you expect them to be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them will obviously return the same values.

viewData[:][2] will not give a list of 'AA26FedGovAccounts', 'AA27StLocGovAccounts', and 'AA28CapitalAccounts' instead you need to iterate over the list. The reason is well explained by @iwin.

The following code is what you need:

```
[item[2] for item in viewData]
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did. I was already doing that for another part of constructing the values field. I got stuck in assuming a function I developed for a similar case would work with this one and didn't consider the changed logic.

Answer (score 1):

**For viewData[2][:]**

```
viewData[2]
```

returns the third element in the outer list:

```
(2010, u'S03', u'AA28CapitalAccounts', 1.79050465110027, 95550709760.0)
```

Then the `[:]` part returns all of that tuple:

---

**For viewData[:][2]**

```
viewData[:]
```

returns the entire outer list

Then the `[2]` part returns the third element:

```
(2010, u'S03', u'AA28CapitalAccounts', 1.79050465110027, 95550709760.0)
```

Which is the same as the other method.

---

Since `[:]` returns a list containing every element, you're not actually slicing anything off, just getting the same list as before.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/) Is a useful, general question about Python's slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the lists with the arrays of `numpy`.
If all of your sub-lists are the same size, it is possible to convert your lists to an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> tmp = [(2010, u'S03', u'AA26FedGovAccounts', 1.90537034315564, 46385659904.0),
           (2010, u'S03', u'AA27StLocGovAccounts', 1.5897291595379, 58351759360.0),
           (2010, u'S03', u'AA28CapitalAccounts', 1.79050465110027, 95550709760.0)]
>>> viewData = np.array(tmp)

# Column-wise
>>> print viewData[:, 2]
[u'AA26FedGovAccounts' u'AA27StLocGovAccounts' u'AA28CapitalAccounts']

# Row-wise
>>> print viewData[2, :] # same as print viewData[2]
[u'2010' u'S03' u'AA28CapitalAccounts' u'1.7905046511' u'95550709760.0']
```

Notice the syntax: `viewData[:, 2]` not `viewData[:][2]`

Comment: I think that's what I had in mind because I am dealing with postgresql tables, so basically arrays.